# Write a command pipeline (Unix)

Tags: shell, unix, find

I have made a few attemps to do the following problem:

> Write a command pipeline to find files in a directory hierarchy (e.g my home directory) that have not been accessed for 30 days and compress them.

Could someone explain what I am doing incorrectly below, I am new to unix:

```
find ~ -type f -atime +30 -exec gzip -cv test
```

Here is the error I am getting btw:

```
find: paths must precede expression: gzip
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D] help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

Comment: Add `{}\;` to the end.  Btw - not at all a C question.

Comment: This has absolutely *nothing* to do with either "kernel" or "c"-language tag. removed *both* and added "unix". Please don't abuse the tagging system.

Comment: I wasn't thinking when I put that as a tag. and I added {}\; (could you explain what this says/does) and i get the same error

`code`find ~ -type f -atime +10 gzip -cv test {}\; `code`

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/339015/what-does-mean-in-linux-command

Comment: What platform are you on?   The error seems to indicate it doesn't like "~" as a path?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04.1, when i run `code` find ~ -type f -atime +10 `code` It starts printing out a bunch of paths such as /home/clmoore3/kernel/linux-3.18.3/arch/mips/include/asm/sni.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `{} \;` to the end.

1. If you want to compress the files in place, don't use the `-c` flag; that writes to stdout instead.

   ```
   find ~ -type f -atime +30 -exec gzip -v {} \;
   ```
2. If you want to bundle the files up into a tarball, then use `tar` instead of `gzip`. Also change `\;` to `+` to pass all the files to a single tar command rather than running tar individually for each file. (Note this only works with GNU find, which is fine on Linux but may not work on other UNIX flavors that ship without the GNU toolset.)

   ```
   find ~ -type f -atime +30 -exec tar -cvf files.tar.gz {} +
   ```

Note that these aren't pipelines, strictly speaking. There's no `|`. Your professor may intend you to solve this problem differently. If so, I'll leave that as an exercise for you to solve.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think i needed -exec here.. Also i appreciate the extra tidbit to bundle the files up!